# updating javascript in the body tag using zend framework

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

Hi not sure if this is possible or not but I want to programaticaly update the <body> tags to change the onload function in my zend framework application.

The App is using layouts so the body tag currently looks like this **<body class="trandra">**

However in one of my views I have a map from google being loaded and it needs the following in the body tag this particular view **<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">**

As you can understand I don't want this to be hardcoded in my layout as this will cause all matter of nightmares with the different views.

How can this be done programaticaly, if at all it is possible?  Im using the headScript functions to add the javascript so is there an equivalant for the body tag?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach one - Use a layout variable**

One idea would be the following:

```
<body class="trandra" <?php echo $this->layout()->bodyScripts ?>>
```

And in your view:

```
<?php
   $this->layout->bodyScripts = 
       'onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"';
```

**Approach two - Additional JS-file that adds event handlers**

Another approach, which is less obtrusive and doesn't affect the HTML whatsoever is to add an additional JS-file in the view that requires the onload- and onunload-handlers. It could look something like this:

```
<?php
   $this->headScript()->appendScript(
                         '/path/to/javascripts/loadGMaps.js');
```

In your loadGMaps.js (using [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/))

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function onLoadHandler() {
    // Code for initializing Google maps here
});

Event.observe(window, 'unload', function onUnloadHandler() {
    // Code for unloading Google maps here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting your Javascript directly in the code, you could also use an non-obstrusive approch : plugging in the javascript when the page is fully loaded.

Have a look, for instance, at a function called [`addOnLoadEvent`](http://thepeninsulasedge.com/blog/?p=65) (can be found on many websites ^^ )

If you are using a JS Framework, it certainly has that kind of feature :

- for jQuery : http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn
- for prototype : http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe

If you register the "plugging-in" with headScript, there should be no need to modify the  tag directly.

Answer (score 1):

Developed something like this recently, I've blogged about it here: http://www.evilprofessor.co.uk/311-zend-framework-body-tag-view-helper/

Demo on site and code is available via github.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on the Zend framework, so I don't know if there is any build in functions for this, but you could do something like this:
*In layout-file:*
    body_params?>>

And then in your controller, you set or add to the body_params:

```
$this->view->body_params='onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"';
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I was looking through some of the suggested solutions and came up with one of my own playing off of some of the ideas I had seen. What I did was I extended Zend_View in my own library files (I'm using a vanilla MVC layout but similar things can be done using a bootstrap.php rather than the Bootstrap class described below)

```
class Custom_View extends Zend_View
{
    protected $bodyAttrs = array();

    public function _setBodyAttr($attrName,$attrValue=null) {
        $attrName = strtolower(strval($attrName));
        if(!(in_array($attrName, HTML::getValidBodyAttrs()))) {
            throw new Zend_Exception(__METHOD__." attrName '$attrName' is not a valid BODY attribute!");
        }
        $this->bodyAttrs[$attrName] = strval($attrValue);
    }

    public function _getBodyAttrsAsString() {
        $bodyAttrs = "";
        if(count($this->bodyAttrs) > 0) {
            $attrs = array();
            foreach($this->bodyAttrs as $_k => $_v) {
                array_push($attrs,sprintf("%s=\"%s\"", $_k, $_v));
            }
            $bodyAttrs = " " . implode(" ", $tags);
        }
        return $bodyAttrs;
    }
}

// some useful tag definitions for HTML
class HTML
{
    // HTML attributes as described by W3C
    public static $BODY_ATTRIBUTES          = array('alink','background','bgcolor','link','text','vlink');
    public static $GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTES         = array('accesskey','class','contenteditable','contextmenu','dir','draggable','dropzone','hidden','id','lang','spellcheck','style','tabindex','title');
    public static $WINDOW_EVENT_ATTRIBUTES   = array('onafterprint','onbeforeprint','onbeforeunload','onerror','onhaschange','onload','onmessage','onoffline','ononline','onpagehide','onpageshow','onpopstate','onredo','onresize','onstorage','onundo','onunload');
    public static $MOUSE_EVENT_ATTRIBUTES    = array('onclick','ondblclick','ondrag','ondragend','ondragenter','ondragleave','ondragover','ondragstart','ondrop','onmousedown','onmousemove','onmouseout','onmouseover','onmouseup','onmousewheel','onscroll');
    public static $KEYBOARD_EVENT_ATTRIBUTES = array('onkeydown','onkeypress','onkeyup');
    public static $FORM_EVENT_ATTRIBUTES     = array('onblur','onchange','oncontextmenu','onfocus','onformchange','onforminput','oninput','oninvalid','onreset','onselect','onsubmit');
    public static $MEDIA_EVENT_ATTRIBUTES    = array('onabort','oncanplay','oncanplaythrough','ondurationchange','onemptied','onended','onerror','onloadeddata','onloadedmetadata','onloadstart','onpause','onplay','onplaying','onprogress','onratechange','onreadystatechange','onseeked','onseeking','onstalled','onsuspend','ontimeupdate','onvolumechange','onwaiting');

    public static function getValidBodyAttrs() {
        return array_merge(self::$BODY_ATTRIBUTES,self::$GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTES,self::$WINDOW_EVENT_ATTRIBUTES,self::$MOUSE_EVENT_ATTRIBUTES,self::$KEYBOARD_EVENT_ATTRIBUTES);
    }
}
```

after creating this file I added a method _initView to the Bootstrap.php file pointed to by the index.php and application.ini at the root of the application directory:

```
protected function _initView()
{
    // Custom_View extends Zend_View
    $view = new Custom_View();

    // Add it to the ViewRenderer
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper( 'ViewRenderer' );
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);

    return $view;
}
```

The new, extended Zend_View now allows adding your body tags along with some simple checking for validity. Modify your layout's body tag to get the attributes:

```
  <body<?= $this->_getBodyAttrs(); ?>>
```

Once you have this set up you can add your body tags to any given view

in the controller with

```
$this->view->_setBodyAttr('key','val');
```

or in the view with

```
$this->_setBodyAttr('key','val');
```